# How can I load Google's Places API and Map API when there's a catch-22?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

Google Maps API requires me to load the script with async defer:

```
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[MY_KEY]&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Meanwhile, Google Places API requires me to load the script normally:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[MY_KEY]&v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places">
</script>
```

If both are on the page, Google Places doesn't work.

If I remove the Map API and nothing else, Google Places works. But, of course, Map doesn't work.

As if that isn't already troublesome enough, Google complains in the console that I'm loading their API twice. Fair enough, but if I combine the request:

```
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[MY_KEY]&callback=initMap&v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places">
</script>
```

...then neither load (with or without "async defer".

Any solutions? Has anyone run into this before? I can't find any answers on Google or Stackoverflow for what seems to be a common use-case (having Places API autosuggest locations in a form, and then a map on the same page show those locations).

Comment: The combined load should work (with `async defer` and a callback or without `async defer` **and** without the callback parameter, but with a different mechanism to run the `initMap function). Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Actually, the answer is that if you're using initMap AND a combined query (both of which are mandatory, anyway) then you need to put all functionality into initMap. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40403251/getting-uncaught-referenceerror-google-is-not-defined-error-using-google-maps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inadvertently discovered the answer from another post which was solving a different problem:

[Getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined" error using Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40403251/getting-uncaught-referenceerror-google-is-not-defined-error-using-google-maps)

The key was:

> If you are loading the API asynchronously (with async, defer,
>   &callback=initMap), you need to put all code that depends on the API
>   inside the callback function

Simply by moving all Places API functionality into the initMap (even though it had nothing to do with initMap) solved the problem entirely and now both are working.

I hope this helps people in future!

Comment: Thanks Matt, helped me!